# prefersLargeTitles not working as expected when used with a UITableView added to a subview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, navigationcontroller

I am currently using two viewControllers to design the following layout presented. It is constituted by a MainController defined in the Storyboard with only a view as a subview,  and a programmatically added CustomController to this subview that inflates it's own view through a xib file. CustomController only has a tableview as childview.

MainController has the navigationBar attached. In CustomController viewDidLoad(), I set prefersLargeTitles to true and it doesn't work as expected when the tableView is scrolled. Title doesn't collapse when tableview scrolled up nor expands when tableview scrolled down.

[image]

Currently I can implement this behaviour only when MainController directly has the tableview as it's first childview:

[image]

But I need to be able to use this behavior using CustomController for app architecture issues.

My guessing, is the inner mechanics of tableview scrolling aren't passed to it's parent navigationController for some reason.

Is there some reference that I need to pass? Maybe modifying the view stack?

Comment: Hello, it seems your question would be better with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Follow the guide lines mentioned in the tutorial https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/large-titles-ios-11/

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends to only show large titles in main views. If your viewcontroller has sub-sections make sure to set navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never either in code or in your storyboard.

In addition problems arise if you need to customize your view around your table. Usually you create a UIViewController for this and then add the views and tableView as required. If the tableView is not the first view in your storyboard, the large title fails to hide automatically.

[image]

Comment: Hello Himan and thank you for your answer. We know about this, but as you can see in our question, our situation is different. We have a UIViewController with a tableView as the first view, but this controller is added as a subView of the main view of another controller. I'm guessing we are breaking the rule of thumb -> "A general rule of thumb is that large titles should be used on a UINavigationController‘s rootViewController only. ", but is this for design purposes, or for logic purposes?

Comment: Yes we can only set this rule to root view controller , after that all the controller can set largeTitleDisplayMode property.